# Re-edited: problem in shaping unbalance panel data to run mixed multinomial regression

Tags: r, reshape, multinomial, mlogit

I have followed 'mlogit' paper to prepare my unbalance panel data for multinomial (panel) regresssion, but I failed to run the regression. After reading some posts, I beleive I have found a good structure for the data, which is similar to this [one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51148/unable-to-provide-random-parameter-with-mlogit). Nevertheless, the mlogit with panel data specification does not work. What I did wrong in the `mlogit.data`? how can I solve it? Did I specify the `mlogit` model correctly?

My dataset is very similar to this one: http://dss.princeton.edu/training/Panel101.dta. Xs are independent variables arranged on a country-year basis (such as economic growth), while the dependent variable is opinion with 4 levels.

```
Panel <- Panel %>% select(country, year,opinion, x1, x2, x3)

Panel_multinomial <- mlogit.data(Panel, shape = 'wide', choice = "opinion", id ="country" , sep = "_")
```

this does not work:

```
 regression <- mlogit(opinion ~ x1+ x2+ x3, data = Panel_multinomial, 
        panel = TRUE, rpar = c(x1= "n", x2= "n", x3="n"), reflevel="1")
```

This does work:

```
regression <- mlogit(opinion ~ 1|x1+ x2+ x3, data = Panel_multinomial, reflevel="1")
```

Comment: You have a couple of problems here: 1) `x` coefficients need to correspond to your `choice` variable. That's why if you look at other examples, what you have as `x` will be labeled something like `option.Agree`, `option.Disagree`. The default behavior of `mlogit.data` is to assume your variables are formatted like that. Two, you need to have a column for `x0`, per above, maybe called `option.StronglyDisagree` - maybe that column should be equal to zero, but `mlogit` works based on comparing the choice to the alternatives, so you need to have a value for the choice *and* the three alternatives.

Comment: Without knowing more about the data set, I don't know if you can infer the correct value for `x0`

Comment: It's also possible this data set isn't of the correct type for an `mlogit` model, depending on what the `x` columns represent. If they represent a factor may have a causal effect on `opinion`, it should work - assuming you can assign a value to `x0`, but if those `x` values do not relate to the four options, this data set is useless for `mlogit`

Comment: You also have to specify the named vector `rpar` to run with `panel = TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, Xs are factors asociated with the choice situation (a country in a given year). One X can be economic growth. If I transform the dataset to run a mlogit, I believe the Xs' values will be the same for each level of choice in a given country-year.

Comment: @Mako212, if I write ```Panel_multinomial <- mlogit.data(Panel, shape = 'wide', choice = "opinion", id ="country" , sep = "_", alt.levels = c(1,2,3,4))``` The dataset turns in a similar format as the dataset used here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51148/unable-to-provide-random-parameter-with-mlogit. I ran the model, but it does not work yet :/